How to stop SvelteKit from refreshing the browser when an API endpoint's code is changed?
In SvelteKit, I have an endpoint like this:
export async function GET(event: RequestEvent) {
    return json({message: "Hello World!"});
}

Simply removing the exclamation mark
export async function GET(event: RequestEvent) {
    return json({message: "Hello World"});
}

causes the browser to refresh which makes no sense. Is there some configuration I can add to stop that from happening?
I tried this:
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        watch: {
            ignored: ['**/src/routes/api/**']
        }
    },
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
});

but this stops the system from registering any changes to the api endpoints.
How do I stop SvelteKit from restarting the browser when code for API endpoints is changed?
